# How do you set a value to the hidden input using Htmlunit?

Tags: java, web-scraping, webclient, htmlunit

I can't set the value of a hidden input using `Htmlunit`. I'm trying to set the value to `HtmlHiddenInput` for 3 fields, but it fails at the 2nd `time(ward)`. After setting the value to the 1st input, ajax calls happen without changing the URL and it sets the list of values to next dropdown where I fail to select the value.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(100000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(120000);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);

//hosp
HtmlHiddenInput hiddenHosp = (HtmlHiddenInput) form1.getInputByName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Hospital_ClientState");
String hosp1 ="{\"logEntries\":[],\"value\":\"\",\"text\":\"Royal Marsden1 Royal Marsden NHS Foundation Trust RM CHELSEA\",\"enabled\":true,\"checkedIndices\":[],\"checkedItemsTextOverflows\":false}";
hiddenHosp.setValueAttribute(hosp1);

//ward
HtmlHiddenInput hiddenWard = (HtmlHiddenInput) form1.getInputByName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Ward_ClientState");
String ward1="{\"logEntries\":[],\"value\":\"%\",\"text\":\"All\",\"enabled\":true,\"checkedIndices\":[],\"checkedItemsTextOverflows\":false}";
hiddenWard.setValueAttribute(ward1);

//status
HtmlHiddenInput hiddenStatus = (HtmlHiddenInput) form1.getInputByName("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Status_ClientState");
String status1 = "{\"logEntries\":[],\"value\":\"%\",\"text\":\"All\",\"enabled\":true,\"checkedIndices\":[],\"checkedItemsTextOverflows\" :false}";
hiddenStatus.setValueAttribute(status1);
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: We need to see your HTML to be able to help. Please read [MCVE].

Comment: @MaxVollmer i have edited the question with html image link at the start ,please have a look...thank you in advance and sorry for my silly mistakes im new here on stackoverflow.

Comment: please help me where im going wrong,am i missing upon any webClient.getOptions().xyz or why value is not getting set to 2nd dropdown(looks dropdown but it is textinput with button which brings dynamic unordered list

Answer (score 0):

And again...
waitForBackgroundScrip() ist not an option. You have to call it e.g. after setting the input.

You have Javascript support disabled but without Javascript Ajax will not work at all. Usually there is no need to change any of the default options. Change them only if you are facing problems and you know what you are doing.

And finally please add at least the version you are using to the question.

Comment: sorry i failed to mention the latest version,and enabling the javascript does not set any of 3 values but disabling it works after turning it false...in other scenario where i am able to set all 3 values but the ajax call which happens after selecting first dropdown does not allows to change the brought values for 2nd dropdown.

Comment: It can't be the latest version because ff38 is not supported by that version.

Comment: before i was using 2.19 but now i have changed it to 2.31 and instead of ff_38 i have set  WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED); please correct me if im going wrong anywhere !!